# JetBrains Toolbox crashes constantly

Tags: java, 16.10

I use Ubuntu 16.10 and my JetBrains Toolbox crashes after few seconds of runtime.

- JetBrains Toolbox 1.0.2095
- Node.js 4.2.6
- Oracle Java 8 (1.8.0_111)

Here is the log: https://gist.github.com/dukeimg/c3430495082a95462fab1ea249bc5b4f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must run it with `--disable-gpu`

Comment: Seems to tix the same issue on 16.04 as well. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently fixed from JetBrains Toolbox 1.1.2143.